# LocalIterator .... Unreachable Statement error

Tags: java, iterator

This is the line which is showing error. i am using netbeans ide for coding

```
   localIterator2 = Collections.list(inetAddresses).iterator(); 
   continue; 
   InetAddress inetAddress = (InetAddress)localIterator2.next();
```

The ERROR IS UNREACHABLE Statement
    The Assigned Value is never used
Please help ... please correct this line of code :/

Comment: @ user2224966 : Please spend some time in asking good questions

Comment: No error? Rename the title and change the question accordingly.

Comment: @ColinD it shows that an error has occurred and an option Run anyway

Comment: @Jayan dude m a beginner pls help

Comment: @ColinD The Error is Unreachable statement

Comment: @asgs Error Unreachable statement

Comment: @ user2224966 : http://stackoverflow.com/faq#etiquette, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18584/how-to-ask-a-smart-question

Comment: @user2224966 You will need to show, at least, the error log and some of the code that pertains to the references (variable names) in the line that causes the error, i.e. the code leading into the error and perhaps the class definitions of each variable type, before anyone can begin to answer the question.

Comment: @user2224966 This might help you [--->Why does Java have an “unreachable statement” compiler error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795585/why-does-java-have-an-unreachable-statement-compiler-error)

Answer (score 2):

You are getting an unreachable statement because of the `continue;` line.

presumably this code is inside of a loop, where `continue` actually has meaning.

The meaning of `continue` is answered [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389741/continue-keyword-in-java), so I will not explain it futher.

When your code hits the `continue` it will not execute the following line: 
 `InetAddress inetAddress = (InetAddress)localIterator2.next();`

To fix this error, remove the `continue;` or the code after it.

Answer (score 1):

Added line numbers for explanation...

```
localIterator2 = Collections.list(inetAddresses).iterator(); 
continue; ////any line after this never reach as the continue prevents it .
InetAddress inetAddress = (InetAddress)localIterator2.next();
```