# Getting error while using Action in OnTouchListener

Tags: android, android-studio, action, ontouchlistener

I am creating an app in which I am implementing `Ontouchlistener`, but I am not getting the correct code. How can I write the correct code for this?

Here is the code I have written for my activity using various tutorials.

```
public class ActivitySwipeDetector
  implements OnTouchListener
{
  private static final int MIN_DISTANCE = 100;
  private static final String logTag = "SwipeDetector";
  private float downX;
  private float downY;
  public Action mSwipeDetected = Action.None;
  private float upX;
  private float upY;

  public Action getAction()
  {
    return this.mSwipeDetected;
  }

  public boolean onTouch(View paramView, MotionEvent paramMotionEvent)
  {
    switch (paramMotionEvent.getAction())
    {
    default:
    case 0:
    case 1:
    }
    float f2;
    do {
        do {
            float f1;
            do {
                //return false;
                this.downX = paramMotionEvent.getX();
                this.downY = paramMotionEvent.getY();
                this.mSwipeDetected = Action.None;
                // return false;
                this.upX = paramMotionEvent.getX();
                this.upY = paramMotionEvent.getY();
                f1 = this.downX - this.upX;
                f2 = this.downY - this.upY;
                if (Math.abs(f1) <= 100.0F)
                    break;
                if (f1 < 0.0F) {
                    Log.i("SwipeDetector", "Swipe Left to Right");
                    this.mSwipeDetected = Action.LR;
                    return false;
                }

            }
            while (f1 <= 0.0F);
            Log.i("SwipeDetector", "Swipe Right to Left");
            this.mSwipeDetected = Action.RL;
            return false;
        }
        while (Math.abs(f2) <= 100.0F);

        if (f2 < 0.0F) {
            Log.i("SwipeDetector", "Swipe Top to Bottom");
            this.mSwipeDetected = Action.TB;
            return false;
        }
    }
    while (f2 <= 0.0F);
    Log.i("SwipeDetector", "Swipe Bottom to Top");
    this.mSwipeDetected = Action.BT;
    return false;
  }

  public boolean swipeDetected()
  {
    return this.mSwipeDetected != Action.None;
  }

  public static enum Action
  {
      LR, RL, TB, BT, None;

      static
    {

      Action[] arrayOfAction = new Action[5];
      arrayOfAction[0] = LR;
      arrayOfAction[1] = RL;
      arrayOfAction[2] = TB;
      arrayOfAction[3] = BT;
      arrayOfAction[4] = None;
    }


  }
}
```

The problem I am currently encountering is in this code:

```
if (f2 < 0.0F) {
    Log.i("SwipeDetector", "Swipe Top to Bottom");
    this.mSwipeDetected = Action.TB;
    return false;
}
```

The compiler is saying "unreachable statement".

Comment: and which error You get?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs- showing error in this code  `if (f2 < 0.0F) {
            Log.i("SwipeDetector", "Swipe Top to Bottom");
            this.mSwipeDetected = Action.TB;
            return false;
        }`  it saying unreachable statement

Comment: Your code looks very confusing to me, I really con´t follow it. But what I think is, Your if statement is never reached because it is inside the do/while loops. Shouldn´t it be while statement?

Comment: Unreachable statements breaks your code as the java compiler does not allow them. See [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795585), and my answer below - you're doing too much work.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should use existing constants to improve readability. See the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html).
2. It seems you're doing too much work. Go over [this tutorial (from Android's documentation)](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html) to see how you can achieve more with less code.

Comment: @Felix- Actually i want to know if this code is correct?

Comment: @Param, your code is confusing and hard to read because of magic numbers such as "0" and "1" (over [MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_DOWN) and ACTION_UP). 
Besides (and I hate myself for saying that), why would you want to implement a OnTouchListener yourself and not use a GestureDetector [as described in the official documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html)? I think you could do a lot more with less code if you use the right tools. Check out GestureDetector.OnGestureListener, it might help.