# Eclipse java dead code warning not working properly

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using eclipse Luna 4.4
I think it is not showing me warning for dead code.

It shows error for

```
if(false){
// Shows warning for dead code here
System.out.println("Dead Code");
}
```

but it doesn't show any warning if i say

```
boolean b = false;
if(b){
// Doesn't show warning for dead code here
System.out.println("Dead Code");
}
```

Somehow I have a little memory that it was giving warning on previous version don't know exactly which.

Once I was doing like

```
boolean b = false;
// code here
// forgot to make it true in some case
if(b){// do things here}  // this gave me warning.
```

Do anyone know what happend here or is there any setting in preferences that can do this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: because b value can change at runtime in second case.. in first case its compile time.

Comment: FWIW, Eclipse Kepler does not warn either. Are you sure it was Eclipse that gave that warning (not FindBugs or something)?

Comment: @Thilo - Not sure if it should warn.... I believe `b` is being assigned some value in the  *some code here part*.

Comment: You do get a dead code warning for the very similar `Boolean b = null; if (b != null){}`.

Comment: This could've been a feature of an additional plugin, that was installed to your eclipse. F.e. [findbugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) can do some static code analysis to highlight such mistakes. By default without similar plugins, I don't think any eclipse version can locate your case #2.

Comment: Don't remember, I was on friend's PC. It could be findbugs. I was not aware of findbugs though. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Java have an "unreachable statement" compiler error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795585/why-does-java-have-an-unreachable-statement-compiler-error)