# "unreachable statement" in a boolean recursion

Tags: java, string, recursion

I need to write a short recursive program for a class that checks if a string - **t** is transformation of another string - **s**. It simply needs to check if every character in **s** is also in **t**.
For ex:

> "sddbs" is **not a transformation** of "sdb"
>
> "sddbs" is **a transformation** of "sddb".

```
public static boolean isTrans (String s, String t) 
{
    if (t.indexOf(s.charAt(0)) != -1)
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
    return isTrans(s.substring(1), t);     
}
```

And still.. the code doesn't work as expected. "unreachable statement" in the last line of the code.

Comment: Because it is… unreachable. There is no way you haven't return before this line.

Comment: The compilation error says it all, what more do you need???

Comment: What you have (the if/else) is equivalent to `return t.indexOf(s.charAt(0)) != -1`

Comment: You question explains answer `unreachable statement`  :)

Comment: If should be obvious that `if (t.indexOf(s.charAt(0)) != -1) return true; else return false;` will always return, hence anything after it will be unreachable. It should also be obvious, that this is an obfuscated version of `return t.indexOf(s.charAt(0)) != -1;`

Comment: BTW, what exactly make "sddbs" is a transformation of "sddb" but not of "sdb"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is homework

Comment: You should read [Why does Java have an "unreachable statement" compiler error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795585/why-does-java-have-an-unreachable-statement-compiler-error) if you don't understand why this happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of **the Law of Excluded Middle**. You can treat `return` as `exit function`.

```
public static boolean isTrans (String s, String t) {
    if (condition)
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
    //the condition must have been true or false so the method has already exited.
    return isTrans(s.substring(1), t);     
}
```

If the `condition` is true, you `return true`, if it's false you `return false`. Otherwise you call recursively. **There is no otherwise.**

Answer (score 2):

The reason is quite simple:

there is no possible way to execute this line:

```
return isTrans(s.substring(1), t);
```

why?:

you have a return **IF** this condition **(t.indexOf(s.charAt(0)) != -1)** is met and another **if not**....

Answer (score 0):

You final `return` statement is unreachable because your method body contains `return` statement for both `if` and `else` condition, hence assuring that the last `return` statement will never be reached.

But besides this I don't understand why you need to write a recursive function, though  a non-recursive function using similar method calls will do the same thing:

```
public static boolean isTrans (String s, String t) 
{
    if (t.indexOf(s) > -1)
        return true;
    else 
        return false;    
}
```

Edit:
As suggested by @Holger you can avoid unnecessary if else and replace your code with:

```
public static boolean isTrans (String s, String t) 
{
    return (t.indexOf(s) > -1) //returns true or false just like your if else

}
```

or even shorter:

```
public static boolean isTrans (String s, String t) 
{
    return t.contains(s); //internally contains() calls indexOf(), similar to what you are doing
}
```

Comment: …and why are you still writing `if(condition) return true; else return false;` instead of just `return condition;`?

Comment: Yes you are right, but just wanted to make my program seem similar to that of OP since he/she seems a beginner. I could have just written `return t.contains(s);` for most simple solution.

Comment: That’s exactly why you should point the OP to the nonsense of such an `if` statement, before it becomes a habit.

Answer (score 0):

According to your recursion method once you enter the if condition it would either return a true or false output. so your code never reaches the recursion statement.
I would like to suggest my way of implementing your transformation program using recursion.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Recursion {

    static int flag;

    public void isTransformation(String str1, String str2) {

        flag = str2.length();
        char ch1[], ch2[];
        ch1 = str1.toCharArray();
        ch2 = str2.toCharArray();

        if (ch1[0] == ch2[0]) {
            flag--;
            if (flag == 0) {
                System.out.println("Transformation");
                return;
            }
            isTransformation(str1.substring(1), str2.substring(1));
        } else
            System.out.println("Not a Transformation");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String str1, str2;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter string 1: ");
        str1 = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter string 2: ");
        str2 = sc.nextLine();
        Recursion r = new Recursion();
        if (str1.length() >= str2.length())
            r.isTransformation(str1, str2);
        else
            r.isTransformation(str2, str1);
        sc.close();
    }

}
```