# java - unreachable statement help (linked lists)

Tags: java, unreachable-statement

So I'm trying to implement a get method for my singly linked list class and I get the error: unreachable statement. I was wondering how can I fix this?

```
public T get(int i) {
    // TODO: Implement this
    Node u = head;
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
        u = u.next;
    }
    return u.x; 
    if (i < 0 || i > n - 1) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    return null;
}
```

Comment: The lines after `return u.x` are unreachable because any code that is placed immediately after `return` will not be run.

Comment: Can you explain in your own words, what `return` does?

Comment: it returns a value to represent the function

Comment: That's correct, so how should a method behave when you said "return that", but still expect it to keep doing other stuff, although it should return something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Java have an "unreachable statement" compiler error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795585/why-does-java-have-an-unreachable-statement-compiler-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lines after `return u.x` are unreachable. Once a value is returned or an exception is thrown, the program exits the method.

Of course, you can still control what happens using an `if` statement:

```
public T get(int i) {
    if (i < 0 || i > n - 1)
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    // TODO: Implement this
    Node u = head;
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        u = u.next;
    return u.x;
}
```

If the condition of the `if` statement isn't true, the program will skip it and return `u.x` instead.

See [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html) for more about returning a value from a method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public T get(int i){
    if (i < 0 || i > n - 1) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    } else {
        Node u = head;
        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
            u = u.next;
        }
        return u.x; 
    }
}
```

Basically, all we're doing is moving the main logic of your method inside your validation logic. If `i` is out of bounds, throw an exception and return null, otherwise, execute your logic and return the result.

Comment: Good catch. Lazy copy/paste.