# I have a Error: error: unreachable statement Error:error: missing return statement

Tags: java, android

I have a Error:

> error: unreachable statement  Error:error: missing return statement

It is running this code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerlayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDrawerlayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawerlayout,R.string.open,R.string.close);

        mDrawerlayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
        mToggle.syncState();

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        if(mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
           return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unreachable statement compile error in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18308159/unreachable-statement-compile-error-in-java)

Comment: It's the `if (mToggle...` after the `return` statement in the `onOptionsItemSelected` function that's unreachable.  Do you understand why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In onOptionsItemSelected() after 1st line if() is unreachable code pls use below.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) { 
if(mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
   return true;
}else{ 
   return false;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

call `super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)` after you have called `mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)`

```
  @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
           return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    if(mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
       return true;
    }
```

Your first statement is a `return` keyword, and that leaves the current method skipping the the next block of code.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning from `onOptionsItemSelected` and there is still some code after return statement. Simply change to below

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
       return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}
```