# Unreachable variable within while loop?

Tags: java

Why is my variable non reachable within the following loop method (i++ is not reachable)?

```
    public String returnFailedImages() {
    int i = 0;
    while(i < failedScreenshotImages.size()) {
        return "<img src='" + failedScreenshotImages.get(i) + "'" + ">" + "</br>";
        i++;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Also if i use a for loop (i++ is not being used)?:

```
    public String returnFailedImages() {
    for(int i = 0;i < failedScreenshotImages.size(); i++) {
        return "<img src='" + failedScreenshotImages.get(i) + "'" + ">" + "</br>";
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: `i++` is unreachable because you return the value before that statement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unreachable code: error or warning?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280787/unreachable-code-error-or-warning)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the name of your method, you want to return multiple elements. You could either return a `List<String>` or concatenate all the `String`s of the failed images :

```
public String returnFailedImages() {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0;i < failedScreenshotImages.size(); i++) {
        result.append("<img src='" + failedScreenshotImages.get(i) + "'" + ">" + "</br>");
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do this:

```
while(i < failedScreenshotImages.size()) {
        return "<img src='" + failedScreenshotImages.get(i) + "'" + ">" + "</br>";
        i++;
}
```

You are actually ending your method in the return statement, therefore you'll never reach the `i++` statement. You should do as follows:

```
public String[] returnFailedImages() {
  int i = 0;
  String[] res = new String[failedScreenshotImages.size()];
  while(i < failedScreenshotImages.size()) {
      res[i] = "<img src='" + failedScreenshotImages.get(i) + "'" + ">" + "</br>";
      i++;
  }
  return res;
}
```

Then you can just iterate through the array to get your images.

Answer (score 0):

because your return statemant is  before the line `i++;`.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning from your method before you reach the line with `i++`. I suspect you want to build a result before which you extend for every different `i`, so that you can return this construct at the end.

Comment: thanks for the message could you add the code that you would use please?

Comment: Have a look at Eran's answer.

Answer (score 0):

A return statement hands over the control to the function it is called from and can place some value / object to the stack. (The return value.)

In your code you place a String (